# How to stop repeitive alerts in WebView runJavascriptAlert OSX

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webview, alert

I've created the below runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage function which displays a javascript alert, however I would like to prevent malicious websites from being able to constantly bring up alerts. I've tried various things but haven't had any luck, so was hoping someone may have an idea on how I can achieve this.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)msg initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
NSString *host = [[NSURL URLWithString:[wv mainFrameURL]] host];
NSString *t = NSLocalizedString(host, @"");
NSString *defaultButton = NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"");


self.currentJavaScriptAlert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:t defaultButton:defaultButton alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:msg];
[currentJavaScriptAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[[frame webView] window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(alertPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:NULL];
```

}